# Error when creating taxonomy term programmatically

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to create a term programmatically:

```
$term = Term::create([
  'vid' => 'vocabulary_mane',
  'name' => 'term_name',
]);

$term->save();
```

---

I can see my term in my overview page in the back-end:

[image: Overview page]

---

But when I click on modify, I will receive an error page:

[image: Error page]

---

In the journal this is the log:

[image: Error log]

---

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution.

the problem was with uppercase/lowercase **vid** value.

If your vocabulary starts with an uppercase letter ex: **'Animal'**, thr vid value will starts with a lowercase letter ex: **'animal'** otherwise you will have an error

This was my problem, hope it will you help.

Comment: Machine names are always lowercase. You used to have to set a parent hierarchy value before in 7.x, not sure if that still applies here.